# Group list by a json key value and create a new list javascript

Tags: javascript, list, group-by

I want to create a new list of JSON objects by grouping data based on the JSON key value.

I have a list with arrays:

```
var models = [
    {   'parentId': '12',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': ['2012']
    }, {
        'parentId': '12',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': ['2012', '2013']
    }, { 
        'parentId': '13',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': ['2012']
    }, {
        'parentId': '14',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': ['2012']
    },
];
```

I want to make a new list that's grouped by parent id so the end result:

```
var models = [ 
   {
    'parentId':'12' 
    'data': [
        { 
            'model': 'r8',
            'year': ['2012']
        }, {
            'model': 'rs5',
            'year':['2012', '2013']
        }
    ]
    }, 
    {
    'parentId':'13'
    'data': [
       {
            'model': 'mustang',
            'year': ['2012']
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    'parentId':'14'
    'data': [
       {
            'model': 'fusion',
            'year': ['2012']
        }
    ]
    }
]
```

I did this way, but it's a little bit slow for big arrays since I used two loops. Can somebody help me to make it more efficient:

```js
 var models = [
        {   'parentId': '12',
            'model': 'r8',
            'year': ['2012']
        }, {
            'parentId': '12',
            'model': 'rs5',
            'year': ['2012', '2013']
        }, { 
            'parentId': '13',
            'model': 'mustang',
            'year': ['2012']
        }, {
            'parentId': '14',
            'model': 'fusion',
            'year': ['2012']
        },
    ];

let newModels = [];

for(let item of models){
    itemData = [];
    let currentParentId = item.parentId;
    itemData.push(item);
    for(let i of models){
        if(i.parentId === currentParentId){
          itemData.push(i);
        }
    }
    newModels.push({ parentId: currentParentId, data : itemData })
}

console.log(newModels)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one `reduce` to make object where you group by `parentId` and then get an array with `Object.values`.

```js
var models = [{"parentId":"12","model":"r8","year":["2012"]},{"parentId":"12","model":"rs5","year":["2012","2013"]},{"parentId":"13","model":"mustang","year":["2012"]},{"parentId":"14","model":"fusion","year":["2012"]}]

const result = models.reduce((r, { parentId, ...rest }) => {
  if(!r[parentId]) r[parentId] = { parentId, data: [rest]}
  else r[parentId].data.push(rest);
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an object indexed by the `parentId`s so you only have to loop through the `models` once, then take its values:

```js
const models = [{
  'parentId': '12',
  'model': 'r8',
  'year': ['2012']
}, {
  'parentId': '12',
  'model': 'rs5',
  'year': ['2012', '2013']
}, {
  'parentId': '13',
  'model': 'mustang',
  'year': ['2012']
}, {
  'parentId': '14',
  'model': 'fusion',
  'year': ['2012']
}];
const modelsByParentId = {};
for (const { parentId, model, year } of models) {
  if (!modelsByParentId[parentId]) {
    modelsByParentId[parentId] = { parentId, data: [] };
  }
  modelsByParentId[parentId].data.push({ model, year });
}
console.log(Object.values(modelsByParentId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const models = [
  {
    'parentId': '12',
    'model': 'r8',
    'year': ['2012]'],
  }, {
    'parentId': '12',
    'model': 'rs5',
    'year': ['2012', '2013']
  }, {
    'parentId': '13',
    'model': 'mustang',
    'year': ['2012']
  }, {
    'parentId': '14',
    'model': 'fusion',
    'year': ['2012']
  }
]

const itemsObject = models.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if (accumulator[currentValue.parentId]) {
    accumulator[currentValue.parentId].push(currentValue)
  } else {
    accumulator[currentValue.parentId] = [currentValue]
  }
  return accumulator
}, {})

const result = Object.keys(itemsObject).map(k => ({parentId: k, data: itemsObject[k]}))

console.log(result)
```